# Controlling AC using Arduino / ESP8266 / ESP32

Tags: arduino, iot, esp8266, esp32, infrared

I want to turn on / off my voltas (TATA) Ac using IR commands using Arduino / nodeMCU / ESP32 any of these boards.

So far I have decoded the IR codes from my AC remote

HEX :

```
0xCE4342CC
```

RAW :

```
4448, -4324, 580, -1600, 572, -548, 548, -1636, 544, -1608, 576, -544, 552, -544, 540, -1608, 576, -548, 548, -544, 552, -1604, 580, -540, 544, -548, 548, -1604, 580, -1600, 572, -548, 548, -1608, 572, -552, 544, -1608, 576, -1600, 572, -1608, 572, -1608, 576, -544, 552, -1604, 576, -1632, 552, -1608, 572, -548, 548, -544, 544, -548, 548, -544, 552, -1624, 548, -548, 548, -544, 552, -1632, 548, -1632, 540, -1612, 572, -548, 548, -544, 552, -544, 544, -548, 548, -544, 552, -544, 552, -540, 544, -548, 548, -1632, 552, -1604, 568, -1608, 572, -1608, 576, -1604, 576, -5216, 4440, -4352, 572, -1608, 576, -544, 552, -1604, 576, -1604, 568, -552, 544, -548, 548, -1600, 572, -552, 544, -552, 544, -1608, 576, -544, 552, -540, 544, -1636, 548, -1604, 568, -552, 544, -1612, 568, -556, 544, -1608, 572, -1604, 580, -1600, 572, -1608, 572, -548, 548, -1608, 576, -1604, 576, -1608, 576, -544, 552, -540, 544, -548, 548, -548, 548, -1600, 572, -548, 548, -548, 548, -1608, 576, -1604, 568, -1608, 572, -548, 552, -544, 540, -552, 544, -548, 548, -544, 544, -552, 544, -548, 548, -544, 552, -1604, 568, -1612, 568, -1608, 576, -1604, 576, -1604, 580,
```

The problem arises when I send these IR codes using IR led. The AC doesn’t respond to the IR codes transmitted by nodeMCU.

My logic was if I replicated the IR codes from remote and retransmitted it using my nodeMCU the AC should accept it. I don’t know what’s wrong.

I am using the following libraries :

```
#include <IRremoteESP8266.h>
#include <IRsend.h>
#include <IRrecv.h>
```

My code for hex :

```
irsend.sendNEC(POWER_ON);
```

My code for RAW :

```
irsend.sendRaw((unsigned int*) results.rawbuf, results.rawlen, 38);
```